# why the function return not right?

Tags: javascript

My function `getComboRefer` returns is not what i'm expecting;

`console.log(getComboRefer(2, 'count'))` should return 11 but instead console is printing `undefined`

```
comboReferData = 
[
  {wagerType: 1,count: 2},
  {wagerType: 2,count: 11}
]


function getComboRefer(type, option) 
{
    comboReferData.forEach(function(item, i){

        if(item.wagerType === type){
          switch(option) 
          {       
            case 'count':
              return item.count

            case 'wt':
              return

            default:
          }
        }
    });
}

console.log(getComboRefer(2, 'count'))
```

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: You return from the `forEach` callback, **not** `getComboRefer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getComboRefer()` function returns nothing: it has no `return` statement. The one in your `.forEach()` will just stop the loop execution.

```js
comboReferData = [
  {wagerType: 1,count: 2},
  {wagerType: 2,count: 11}
]

function getComboRefer(type, option) {
      let result;

      comboReferData.forEach(function(item, i) {
        if (item.wagerType === type) {
          result = item[option];
        }
      });
      
      return result;
    }

console.log(getComboRefer(2, 'count'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take `find` and return the wanted property.

```js
function getComboRefer(type, option) {
    return (comboReferData.find(o => o.wagerType === type) || {})[option];
}

var comboReferData = [{ wagerType: 1, count: 2 }, { wagerType: 2, count: 11 }];

console.log(getComboRefer(2, 'count'))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `forEach` loop doesn't return any value, also you didn't return any value from your function, if you want to return value you can use `map`, also you should return the value from your function:

```
comboReferData = [
  {wagerType: 1,count: 2},
  {wagerType: 2,count: 11}
]

function getComboRefer(type, option) {
      const res = comboReferData.map(function(item, i){
        if(item.wagerType === type){
          switch(option) {
            case 'count':
              return item.count
            case 'wt':
              return
            default:
          }
        }
      });
    return res

    }


console.log(getComboRefer(2, 'count'))
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using foreach method you can try to use for loop as below

```
function getComboRefer(type, option) {
   for(let i=0;i<comboReferData.length;i++){
       let item=comboReferData[i];
       if(item.wagerType === type){
        switch(option) {
          case 'count':
            return item.count
          case 'wt':
            return
          default:
        }
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing a function to `forEach`, your `return` statement belongs to that function. Its not the `return` statement of your `getComboRefer` function.